# using a4j:repeat var in binding

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces, components

I wanted to ask if it's possible to use a var attribute inside an a4j:repeat tag, as a binding of an inner componente. For example

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{myController.bindingComponents}" var="component">
  <h:panelGroup binding="#{component}"/>
</a4j:repeat>
```

I tried this already, however component is null when the binding expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The `binding` attribute is evaluated during view build time (like the `id` attribute and all tag handlers), while the `value` of `<a4j:repeat>` as being an UI component is evaluated during view render time. So at the moment the `binding` attribute evaluates, the `#{component}` is `null`, because the `<a4j:repeat>` hasn't run at that point.

If you think once more about it, it should make completely sense: there's only **one** `<h:panelGroup>` in the JSF component tree which renders its output multiple times. It's not true that multiple `<h:panelGroup>` components will be generated this way, as you seemed to expect.

To achieve the particular functional requirement you've had in mind, you probably want to use a view build time iterating tag instead, like JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Ok, I understand... however using c:forEach isn't giving me the desired approach. What could be an alternative?,I need to achieve dynamically generated forms inside each panel that's looped inside the a4j:repeat tag... The form is obviously created in code, Could I achieve this behaviour bindng to a single panelGroup in a managedBean?.